# Upvoting posts with Flutter and Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and am trying to code my very first application where I am building a feature where users can upvote posts.
All i have in flutter is just an IconButton that can switch between upvote and un-vote.
However, when i leave the post and re-enter, the state (whether i already upvoted it or not) will appear the same as how i initially coded the screen to be. (It will always appear as it hasn't been upvoted)
How do i implement whether a user has already upvoted a post or not and save the state whenever i enter the post?
Also, i need to have a counter to count the number of votes the post have.

How do i code this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Map<String, bool> as an attribute in your post class, where the String is the userId and the bool a flag that points if is upvoted or downvoted. And in your method you can check like this. Downvoted here can be Not Voted also if it's what you want.

```
bool isUpVoted;

 handleVotePost(Post post) {
    //check if the userId upVoted or downvoted the post
    isUpVoted = post.votes[userId] == true;
    if (isUpVoted) {
      //Method that update the post with the downvote for the userId
      isUpVoted = false;
      postService.votePost(userId, post, isUpVoted);
      
    } else if (!isUpVoted) {
     //Method that update the post with the upvote for the userId
      isUpVoted = true;
      postService.votePost(userId, post, isUpVoted);

    }
  }
```

The counter will be the length of the map. The amount of true for upvoted and the amount of false to downvoted.

Comment: oh I see thank you so much! can I ask why is the state (whether it is updated or not) not saved when I leave the page and re-enter it even though I used the setState() method? Is it because it has to be uploaded to firebase? Thank you! @JRamos29

Comment: Yes you need to persist your data in someway. It can be in Firebase or locally in the device, by example [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), etc. to not lose the vote information (state) when the user closes the app. And then, when the user re-opens the app, you can implement some method to retrieve the information about his votes from your app's database.

Comment: The setState is used to tell flutter that something currently changed in your app state and so it can rebuild your widgets with the changes while the app is running. When you close the app and reopens, the widgets/pages will be shown with initial state if you not saved them.

Comment: To maintain your state when change from a page to another while the app is running you can use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) or some kind of state management like Bloc, Mobx, Provider, etc. But if you do not persist the data that reflects the state that you want, your app will always start with initial state when you close and reopen it.

Comment: It's alright. You can accept my answer if helped you on what you needed.

Comment: hi! is it possible to add map in firebase? I've tried searching if its possible but failed to find anything useful. thank you!

Comment: Yes, if fact Firebase any document is a map. And at Firebase Console, when you create a document and add a new field, you can choose the type map.

Comment: hi! you mentioned that the counter will be the length of the map, but can I ask how can I get a snapshot of the map because theres an error that says internallinkedhashmap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of Map<String, bool> when i tried to retrieve a DocumentSnapshot? thank you!!!

Comment: This is because Firebase returns a Map<String, dynamic> and can't infers the type for the map's value if you declared as bool. So you can change your map to Map<String, dynamic> that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply setstate method on click on the icon button you need to store value upvote or downvote in database and in your initstate method first you have to load data then set state of upvote or downvote and also u can count from database.